# HTML select value fetching from Mysql table

Tags: php, html, post

```
<select name="mac">
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM wifi_mac");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<option  value=\"mac\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

above code has an issue instead of posting a mac value from the table wifi_mac it sends a "mac" string instead of actual value from the table.

table: wifi_mac
columns: varchar id, varchar name, varchar mac, varchar model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't selected the `mac` column in your query, and it would return a mac string since you just put the `"mac"` which is a `string`, so try this:

```
<select name="mac">
<?php

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, mac FROM wifi_mac");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option  value=\"" . $row['mac'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you output only the string mac. Should have been `$row['mac']`

```
<select name="mac">
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM wifi_mac");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<option  value=\"".$row['mac']."\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```